# How do I populate the data from my Stored Procedure into my winform?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm pretty new to programming and have run into a problem with a basic application I am working on. I have a person class which resembles this...

```
        Person
        {
              SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=True; Data                       
              Source=ME\MyPRESS;Initial Catalog=TEST5");
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_employee", conn);
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
              SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

         while (dr.Read())

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            {
                department = dr["dept_name"].ToString();
                fname = dr["emp_first_name"].ToString();
                lname = dr["emp_last_name"].ToString();
                email = dr["emp_email"].ToString();
                phone = dr["emp_phone"].ToString();
                position = dr["emp_position"].ToString();
                address1 = dr["emp_address1"].ToString();
                address2 = dr["emp_address2"].ToString();
                city = dr["emp_city"].ToString();
                state = dr["emp_state"].ToString();
                postal_code = dr["emp_postal_code"].ToString();

                // department = txtFirst_name.Text;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // 3. close the reader
            if (dr != null)
            {
                dr.Close();
            }

            // close the connection
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

protected string department;

```
    public string Department
    {
         get { return department; }
         set { department = value; }
    }
    protected string fname;

    public string Fname
    {
        get { return fname; }
        set { fname = value;}
    }

    protected string lname;

    public string Lname
    {
        get { return lname; }
        set { lname = value; }
    }

    protected string email;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }



    protected string position;

    public string Position
    {
      get { return position; }
      set { position = value; }
    }

    protected string address1;

    public string Address1
    {
        get { return address1; }
        set { address1 = value; }
    }

    protected string address2;

    public string Address2
    {
        get { return address2; }
        set { address2 = value; }

    }

    protected string phone;

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return phone; }
        set { phone = value; }

    }

    protected string city;

    public string City
    {
        get { return city; }
        set { city = value; }
    }

    protected string state;

    public string State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set { state = value; }
    }

    protected string postal_code;

    public string Postal_Code
    {
        get { return postal_code; }
        set { postal_code = value; }

    }
```

}

I have a form and a db with a stored procedure to retrieve the data as you can see above.... 
Where I am lost is in wiring up my form to display the record from the stored procedure.

Comment: You'll need some form of ORM (object-relational-mapping). Several books have been dedicated to this topic, and there is a good deal of debate as to the best approach. I suggest you google the above term and see what fits you best.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relational databases and OO languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791291/relational-databases-and-oo-languages)

Comment: You definitely do not need an ORM to do this.  You just need to write your columns values to the .Value properties of your forms display controls.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: And this question has almost nothing to do with that other question.

Comment: As it stands, that code won't even compile!

Also your fields should be `private` not `protected` and since your properties have no logic in the getters and setters, if you're using .NET 3.5+ you can use auto implemented properties `public string Email { get; set; }` not not bother with fields at all.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - The OP describes a 'Person' class that s/he wants to fill with data from a relational table. After this the question gets a bit confusing, but it sounds like the Form should then be filled with data (from the database, maybe via the 'Person' class). Sounds like ORM to me.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: It sounds like every Windows App, ever.  ORM is an option, but the vast majority of Windows/DB apps work just fine without one. And the referenced question is asking a general design question about LINQ, which is already an ORM.  This question is  asking the very simple coding question of how to put data values onto a form.  The only similarities are C# and using a database which describes about 40% of the question in SO.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to define a constructor for your Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string Department, string fName /* etc */)
    {
        this.Department = Department;
        this.fName = fName;

        // and so on for all the fields
    }

    // the rest of the class definition goes here
}
```

Then when looping through the data, create a Person object using that constructor.  Return the new Person object from your function.

Answer (score 0):

That helps! I have it up and running now....

public Person(int id)
        {

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=True; Data Source=JODIEPC\XPRESS;Initial Catalog=TEST5");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_EmployeeSelect", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;



        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            department = dr["dept_name"].ToString();
            fname = dr["emp_first_name"].ToString();
            lname = dr["emp_last_name"].ToString();
            email = dr["emp_email"].ToString();
            phone = dr["emp_phone"].ToString();
            position = dr["emp_position"].ToString();
            address1 = dr["emp_address1"].ToString();
            address2 = dr["emp_address2"].ToString();
            city = dr["emp_city"].ToString();
            state = dr["emp_state"].ToString();
            postal_code = dr["emp_postal_code"].ToString();

        }


    }

   protected int id;
   protected string fname;
   protected string lname;
   protected string department;
   protected string email;
   protected string position;
   protected string address1;
   protected string address2;
   protected string phone;
   protected string city;
   protected string state;
   protected string postal_code;





    public int Id
   {
       get { return id; }
       set { id = value; }
   }



    public string Department
    {
       get { return department; }
       set{ department = value; }
    }

    public string Fname
    {
        get { return fname; }
        set { fname = value; }
    }
    public string Lname
    {
        get { return lname; }
        set { lname = value; }
    }
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }

    public string Position
    {
      get { return position; }
      set { position = value; }
    }

    public string Address1
    {
        get { return address1; }
        set { address1 = value; }
    }

    public string Address2
    {
        get { return address2; }
        set { address2 = value; }

    }

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return phone; }
        set { phone = value; }

    }

    public string City
    {
        get { return city; }
        set { city = value; }
    }
     public string State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set { state = value; }
    }
    public string Postal_Code
    {
        get { return postal_code; }
        set { postal_code = value; }

    }
}
```

---------winform---------------
 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person Emp = new Person(Int32.Parse(txtId.Text));
            txtFirstName.Text = Emp.Fname;
            txtLastName.Text = Emp.Lname;
            txtEmail.Text = Emp.Fname;
            txtPhone.Text = Emp.Phone;
            txtDepartment.Text = Emp.Department;
            txtPosition.Text = Emp.Position;
            txtAddress1.Text = Emp.Address1;
            txtAddress2.Text =Emp.Address2;
            txtCity.Text = Emp.City;
            txtState.Text = Emp.State;
            txtPostalCode.Text = Emp.Postal_Code;
        }
    }
It's not the most creative way of going about it but it works....

Thanks alot guys....